# Expand The App bar in Flutter to Allow Multi-Line Title?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Does anyone know how I can create an app bar with a multi-line title, as per the material guidelines show here?

https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-top.html#anatomy

[image: Multi-line app bar]

Any ideas how to do this? It seems like it should be straightforward given that it's part of the material guidelines! Worth pointing out that the title is user defined, so I want to allow the app bar to expand from a single line to multiple lines (perhaps with a limit imposed) depending on user input.

Mike

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not implemented yet.

However you can achieve similar results by using `SliverAppBar` designed for `CustomScrollView`.

Bear in mind that this is not optimal though. As it required hard coding the size of the icons and stuff. Due to `FlexibleSpacebar` not having width constraint.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_project/materialSheet.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverMultilineAppBar(
            title: "Summer Trip to Tokyo and Kyoto",
            leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SliverMultilineAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Widget leading;
  final List<Widget> actions;

  SliverMultilineAppBar({this.title, this.leading, this.actions});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);

    double availableWidth = mediaQuery.size.width - 160;
    if (actions != null) {
      availableWidth -= 32 * actions.length;
    }
    if (leading != null) {
      availableWidth -= 32;
    }
    return SliverAppBar(
      expandedHeight: 120.0,
      forceElevated: true,
      leading: leading,
      actions: actions,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        title: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: availableWidth,
          ),
          child: Text(title, textScaleFactor: .8,),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a shame, but thanks for letting me know. Seems very odd to not have implemented it yet. Is there a way to find out if they plan to? Or to raise it with the team to request it?

Comment: You can look on their github and potentially raised an issue.

Answer (score 9):

Try below code. This will give multi-line where you can also control the text styling.
Use Text instead of RichText if you do not want different style for all the lines.

```
             AppBar(
                title: RichText(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  text: TextSpan(
                      text: "Developer Developer",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      children: <TextSpan>[
                        TextSpan(
                          text: '\nTrip List',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]
                  ),
                ),
                backgroundColor: MissionGPSTheme.themeBlueColor
            ),
```

[image]

Comment: This fix does not seem to adapt to a 3 lines text

Comment: add one more TextSpan inside children: <TextSpan>.
Read up on how RichText & TextSpan work.

Answer (score 8):

You can use RichText:

```
          SliverAppBar(
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          background: Container(
            color: Colors.indigoAccent,
          ),
          title: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: Constants.homePageTitle,
                style: textTheme.headline,
              ),
              TextSpan(text: "\n"),
              TextSpan(
                text: Constants.homePageSubtitle,
                style: textTheme.subtitle,
              )
            ]),
          ),
          titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, bottom: 20),
        ),
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
        expandedHeight: 150.0,
      ),
```

Answer (score 5):

AppBar will let you get close to this, however you do have to indicate the height of the bottom PreferredSize widget, according to your text length, which isn't ideal.

[image]

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {}),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {}),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert), onPressed: () {}),
      ],
      bottom: PreferredSize(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(80.0, 0.0, 80.0, 16.0),
          child: Text(
            "Summer Trip to Tokyo and Kyoto",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 24.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        preferredSize: Size(0.0, 80.0),
      ),
    ),
    body: Text("..."),
  );
}
```

Comment: I think you need to illustrate more @AyaElsisy :)  what problem are you getting?

Answer (score 4):

This piece of code will create a custom `Scaffold` with an `AppBar` that supports receiving no title, a title, and a title and a subtitle. In case you don't provide a title, it will show a given text (in the example, the name of the app), while in case you set a title and a subtitle, it will use a two lines style with the proper Material Design text style.

[image: An AppBar with one line and two lines]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TwoLinesAppBarScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget body;
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;

  TwoLinesAppBarScaffold({this.body, this.title = "QuitNow!", this.subtitle});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget widget;

    if (subtitle == null) {
      widget = Text(title);
    } else {
      widget = RichText(
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
        text: TextSpan(
            text: title,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            ),
            children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(
                text: '\n$subtitle',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                ),
              ),
            ]),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: widget,
        ),
        body: Center(child: body));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by replacing the "title" property of AppBar with "flexibleSpace":

```
  Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      flexibleSpace: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Title Line One'),
            Text('Title Line Two'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    body: body
  ),
```

If overflow occurs due to height, just wrap AppBar with a PreferredSize widget and set the height to a higher value than the default one:

```
  Scaffold(
    appBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100),
      child: AppBar(...),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this in you appbar

```
AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        title: Text(
          softWrap: true,
          maxLines: null,
         'This is a big text in appbar')
        )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Found some solution with [textPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextPainter-class.html)  to count text height depending on it's style and screen width and pass it to `AppBar` `toolbarHeight`

```
class AppBarHeightCalc {
  String title;
  double width;
  AppBarHeightCalc({
    required this.title,
    required this.width,
  });

double horizontalPadding = 32;
double actionsWidth = 48;
final style = TextStyle(fontSize: 26);

  double calculateHeight() {
    TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter()
      ..text = TextSpan(text: title, style: style)
      ..textDirection = TextDirection.ltr
      ..layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: width - horizontalPadding);
    return (textPainter.size.height);
  }

double calculateHeightWithActions() {
    TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter()
      ..text = TextSpan(text: title, style: style)
      ..textDirection = TextDirection.ltr
      ..layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: width - actionsWidth - horizontalPadding);
    return (textPainter.size.height);
  }
}

class AppBarExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppBarExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String title =
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 33 nostrum neque qui possimus fugit ex fugiat';
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final appBarHeight = AppBarHeightCalc(title: title, width: screenWidth);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            title,
            maxLines: 3,
          ),
          toolbarHeight: appBarHeight.calculateHeight(),
        ),
        body: Center());
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).