# How to make AppBar with Icon below title?

Tags: flutter

I want to have an `IconButton` below title of an `AppBar`. I tried `Column`, but I had problem with center all items there and with overflowing bottom.

My Code:

```
appBar: new AppBar(
    title: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            new Text('App Title'),
            IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(new IconData(0xe902, fontFamily: 'Ionicons')),
                onPressed: () {},
            )
        ],
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
    actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(new IconData(0xe906, fontFamily: 'Ionicons')),
            onPressed: () {},
        )
    ],
),
```

[It should looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3nIK.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
appBar: AppBar(
  centerTitle: true,
  title: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text("App Title"),
      GestureDetector(
        child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
        onTap: () {
          // handle your click here
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50764558/expand-the-app-bar-in-flutter-to-allow-multi-line-title). Maybe you can try to reduce the sizes of your Text & IconButton widgets to avoid overflow (it won't look good) and add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center` in your Column widget to center the Column's children in it's cross axis.

If none of that will work, maybe you can build your own appbar widget since everything is a widget on flutter..