# AppBar Text overflow visible

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to have an appbar that expands if its title spans multiple lines?

If this isn't be possible, is there another solution for this problem?

```
AppBar(
    elevation: 0,
    automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
    scrolledUnderElevation: 2,
    title: Row(
        children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Text(
                    //event.eventName!,
                    'This is a very long title that occupies several lines',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.visible,

                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                ),
            ),
        ],
    ),
    actions: [
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => EditEvent(event: event)));
            },
            child: const Text(
                'Edit',
        ))
    ],
),
```

Comment: According to this [documented issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30547), dynamically sized AppBars are not supported currently. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50764558/expand-the-app-bar-in-flutter-to-allow-multi-line-title/56858416#56858416) has some workarounds that might work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can wrap `AppBar` in `PreferredSize`

   ```
   PreferredSize(
     preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(72.0), // set the height of the AppBar
      child: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'This is a very long title that occupies several lines',
          overflow: TextOverflow.visible, // allow the text to overflow
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
   ```
2. As @Rémi Rousselet suggested use `SliverAppBar`

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverMultilineAppBar(
            title: "Summer Trip to Tokyo and Kyoto",
            leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SliverMultilineAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Widget leading;
  final List<Widget> actions;

  SliverMultilineAppBar({this.title, this.leading, this.actions});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);

    double availableWidth = mediaQuery.size.width - 160;
    if (actions != null) {
      availableWidth -= 32 * actions.length;
    }
    if (leading != null) {
      availableWidth -= 32;
    }
    return SliverAppBar(
      expandedHeight: 120.0,
      forceElevated: true,
      leading: leading,
      actions: actions,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        title: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: availableWidth,
          ),
          child: Text(title, textScaleFactor: .8,),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output

[image]